# Material-UI Autocomplete/Popper - How to prevent x-scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working on implementing the Material-UI Autocomplete component, and I want each option label to display an icon and some text. However, I only want the popper to be the full width of the text input, and then add an ellipsis to any text that would normally overflow on the Popper width.

In my `renderOption` method, if I return `<Typography noWrap>"Text"</Typography>` it succesfully forces the text to have an ellipsis, but if I put it in a Grid or Flex box in order to also include the icon, then the Popper component will be able to scroll horizontally. Is there a way to fix the Popper viewport to the width of Autocomplete, so that way the text in the `renderOption` method will wrap?

```
import React from 'react';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import GraphicEqIcon from '@material-ui/icons/GraphicEq';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Autocomplete } from '@material-ui/lab';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

function SearchBarDisplay({ options = [], onChange, onSelectValue, value = '' }) {
    function getOptionLabel(option) {
        if (option.name) {
            return option.name;
        } else if (option.username) {
            return option.username;
        } else if (option.type === 'advanced') {
            return option.value;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    function renderOption(name, username, type) {
        if (name) {
            return (
                <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={1} wrap={'nowrap'}>
                    <GraphicEqIcon />
                    <Grid item>
                        <Typography noWrap>{name}</Typography>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            );
        } else if (username) {
            return (
                <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={1} wrap={'nowrap'}>
                    <PersonIcon />
                    <Grid item>
                        <Typography noWrap>{username}</Typography>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            );
        } else if (type === 'advanced') {
            return (
                <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
                    <SearchIcon />
                    <Grid item>
                        <Typography
                            noWrap={true}
                            color="textSecondary">{`See more results for "${value}"`}</Typography>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            id="autocomplete"
            options={options}
            getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option._id === value._id}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => getOptionLabel(option)}
            onChange={(event, value) => {
                onSelectValue(value);
            }}
            onInputChange={(event, value) => onChange(value)}
            renderOption={({ name, username, type }) => renderOption(name, username, type)}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    placeholder="Search for podcasts or users"
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    InputProps={{
                        ...params.InputProps,
                        startAdornment: (
                            <>
                                <InputAdornment position="start">
                                    <SearchIcon />
                                </InputAdornment>
                            </>
                        )
                    }}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
}

export default SearchBarDisplay;
```

Answer (score 1):

To change each option label to have just one line with ellipsis (... - tree dots) instead two or more lines, do you need to change your `renderOption` property to the follow code:

```
<Autocomplete
...
getOptionLabel={(option: any) => `${option.label} (${option.code})`}
renderOption={(option) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div style={{ textOverflow: 'ellipsis', overflow: "hidden", whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
            {option.label} ({option.code})
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
...
/>
```

See an example with the countries list at CodeSandbox that I did: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-with-ellipsis-i8hnw